# Fried SD card help

Tags: sd-card

So I'm in a bit of a pickle here and am hoping someone here can give me some good advice. Recently my RaspberryPi model 3 stopped working and the SD card was getting terribly hot. I figured the Pi had shorted somewhere and my board was toast. I then went to reformat my micro SD card in my laptop and to my dismay that was also fried, but it got really hot just like it was getting in the pi.

I figure there are two possibilities: My pi shorted and in turn fried the SD card or my SD card got all screwy and that is why my pi isn't working correctly.

The problem is that I want to check if the Pi is still working but I don't really want to just boot the Pi on another SD card as it might just toast it like it did the last one.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should go about diagnosing my pi without frying another SD card?

EDIT: I checked the 3.3V GPIO Pin as well as the 3.3V pin on the microSD slot and got ~4V across both.

Comment: Check the 3.3V level (which is SD Card supply).

Comment: I checked the 3.3V GPIO Pin as well as the 3.3V pin on the microSD slot and got ~4V across both.

Comment: Your Pi is DEAD.

Comment: @JeremyArsenault Please add the [rip](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/rip/info) tag. My sympathies.

Comment: have you tested your voltmeter?

Comment: No I guess I haven't, didn't know that was something I should do. Just bought a replacement Pi but will give it another check!